# Why would the collect function not work in the given rust code?

Tags: rust

I am trying to reverse the words in a given string. For example - "John is amazing" would return "amazing is John". Following code snippet works:

```rs
pub fn reverse_words1(input: &str) -> String {

    let words: Vec<&str> = input.split(" ").collect();
    let mut reversed: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

    for w in words.iter().rev() {
        reversed.push(w);
    }

    reversed.join(" ")
}
```

However, the following would not work:

```rs
pub fn reverse_words2(input: &str) -> String {

    let words: Vec<&str> = input.split(" ").collect();

    // Error here 
    let reversed: Vec<&str> = words.iter().rev().collect();

    reversed.join(" ")
}
```

The error is:

```
a value of type `Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&&str`.
```

I have three questions here:

1. Why is the iterator providing reference to the `&str` instead of direct access to `&str` since it is already a slice/reference to a string?
2. Why does the first function work and second doesn't?
3. The return type of the function is `String` while I am trying to join `Vec<&str>`. Shouldn't the `join` result in a `&str` instead of `String` type? Is rust doing automatic conversion of the value?

Finally, how can I fix the second function so that I don't have to maintain my own `for` construct?

Comment: 1. `iter` is defined to provide a reference, it just happened that the inner type is `&str`, so it becomes an iterator over `&&str`. 2. `.push` converts the double reference into just `&str` 3. `&str` is just a reference, but it by itself doesn't own the memory **storage**. `String` has storage, it can be allocated and owned, unlike `&str` which is essentially borrowed, or is a static string literal

Comment: `.join("")` on a `Vec<&str>` probably means you should be collecting directly into a `String`. Maybe you meant `.join(" ")` to re-add spaces between words?

Comment: Nitpick: It is better to split by character than string when possible (`split(' ')`).

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2515cdd5b0f85feeb288be1ba6f0b57 then https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e4e45fa5f4f7ecfc4937b47c08a60c3c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a value to a function, it will automatically be dereferenced if needed. So in your for loop:

```rs
for w in words.iter().rev() {
    reversed.push(w);
}
```

`w` is of type `&&str`, and it gets automatically dereferenced into `&str` to match the type required by `push`.

You can fix the second one by adding [`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied).

```rs
let reversed: Vec<&str> = words.iter().rev().copied().collect();
```

For why you get a `String` instead of `&str`, this is because the return of `join` is dependent on the type of the items and the type of the separator.

```rs
pub fn join<Separator>(
    &self,
    sep: Separator
) -> <[T] as Join<Separator>>::Output
```

In the docs for [`Join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.Join.html#impl-Join%3C%26str%3E-for-%5BS%5D), there is an implementation for `[&str]` and separator `&str` to output `String`.

```rs
impl<S: Borrow<str>> Join<&str> for [S] {
    type Output = String;
```

`Borrow<str>` is another trait, but the only relevant thing here is that `&str` implements `Borrow<str>`.

The `Join` trait has been implemented as such because it needs a mutable, growable type to put the data in. It can't return `&str` because the ones it has access to (in the slice) are immutable, plus since it is a reference it can't create a new one because that would require something outside the function to own it. `String` solves those problems.

Note that when you provide a `char` to `split` instead of a `&str`, you can iterate it in reverse, so you don't actually need the intermediate `Vec`.

```rs
let reversed: Vec<&str> = input.split(' ').rev().collect();
```

And then you can collect directly into a `String`.

```rs
pub fn reverse_words2(input: &str) -> String {
    input.split(' ').rev().collect()
}
```

If you need a nonempty separator, you can do some iterator gymnastics.

```rs
// Adds ", " between each word
pub fn reverse_words2(input: &str) -> String {
    input
        .split(' ')
        .rev()
        .flat_map(|s| [", ", s])
        .skip(1)
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about dereferencing, especially this statement _When you pass a value to a function, it will automatically be dereferenced if needed._

Comment: @HarshalPatil it is one of the automatic type coercions https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html also related is method resolution https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Alexey, `Vec<T>::iter` produces an iterator with item type `&T`. Since you have a `Vec<&str>`, this means the iterator it produces has item type `&&str`.

You can just fix this by consuming the vector with `into_iter` instead:

```rust
pub fn reverse_words2(input: &str) -> String {

    let words: Vec<&str> = input.split(" ").collect();

    let reversed: Vec<&str> = words.into_iter().rev().collect();

    reversed.join("")
}
```

But it would be better to avoid creating the vector in the first place by collecting from a reversed iterator directly:

```rust
pub fn reverse_words3(input: &str) -> String {
    let words = input.rsplit(" "); // notice `rsplit` rather than `split`
    let reversed: Vec<&str> = words.collect();
    reversed.join(" ")
}
```

Comment: This is also correct answer. But only one answer can be marked as correct.